# Extracting elements from a nested array whilst incrementing

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to extract each element from each array within an array. E.g:

```
const arr = [[a, b, c], [d, e, f], [g, h, i], [j, k, l]];
```

I want to iterate over the nested arrays, extracting the first element (a, d, g, j). Then I want to iterate back over the nested arrays, extracting the second element (b, e, h, k), so on and so on.....

I'm struggling to get my head around how I would achieve this?

Comment: Use nested loops. The main loop iterates over the indexes of the nested elements you want (0 for the first element, then 1 for the second element, etc.), the inner loop iterates over the main array elements.

Comment: What do you mean by *extracting*? Do you want to loop over the array and have access to the elements? Do you want to save them somewhere? Could you elaborate a bit? What is the expected result/output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate with the length of the first element

```js
const arr = [
  ["a", "b", "c"],
  ["d", "e", "f"],
  ["g", "h", "i"],
  ["j", "k", "l"],
]

for (let i = 0; i < arr[0].length; i++) {
  const temp = arr.map((el) => el[i])
  console.log(temp)
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the required output. Transpose of matrix:

```js
arr = [
  ["a", "b", "c"],
  ["d", "e", "f"],
  ["g", "h", "i"],
  ["j", "k", "l"],
]
output = [];
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
for(var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
    if(!i) output[j] = [];
    output[j][i] = arr[i][j];
}
}

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could trnaspose the array and get the nested arrays.

```js
const
    transpose = array => array.reduce((r, a) => a.map((v, i) => [...(r[i] || []), v]), []),
    array = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i'], ['j', 'k', 'l']];

for (const items of transpose(array)) console.log(...items);
```

Answer (score 0):

Find below the code snippet-

```
const arr = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i'], ['j', 'k', 'l']];
for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
  let j=i
  if (j !== arr.length-1){
    for(let k=0; k< arr.length; k++){
      console.log(arr[k][j])
    }
    console.log('\n')
  }
}
```

output-

```
a
d
g
j


b
e
h
k


c
f
i
l
```